# SortedMap with Comparator ClassCast Exception

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, sortedmap

Why am getting a ClassCastException at (Person p2 = (Person) o2;) in overridden compare method .  :(

Actually Instead of Person Object the values in compare overridden method is coming as "Jim" and "Jack" (Key values). So the Cast Cast Exception . But Why is it coming with keys not values i,e the Person object , Why is it only applied for keys . Are there any other way to sort it based on values .

Please correct me if am wrong

1) We can Pass the comparator object in the TreeMap which will sort it accordingly.?

2) Always the Sorting is performed over Keys . ?

3) How can we sort a Map over its values without using anymore collection object (Is it possible) and why is not supported by default ?

public class HashTableExamples {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SortedMap persorSorted = new TreeMap(new Comparator() {

        @Override 
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            Person p2 = (Person) o2;
            return 2;
        }
    });

    Person p = new Person(10);
    Person p1 = new Person(20);
    persorSorted.put("Jim", p);
    persorSorted.put("Jack", p1);
    Iterator sortedit = persorSorted.entrySet().iterator();
    while (sortedit.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) sortedit.next();
        Person pw = (Person) pairs.getValue();
        System.out.println("From SortedMap : " + pw.getAge());
    }
}

public static class Person {
    Person(int agevalue) {
        this.age = agevalue;
    }

    private int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what a TreeMap does. It sorts on ***keys***. There are some hackish ways of getting around this, involving storing the map in the comparator.

Comment: You should use generics here, and create a proper `Comparator<String>`. Such code wouldn't even compile if you used generics correctly.

Comment: @MattBall Sorry for not using generics i was just writing the code to sort it based on values . I guess even if we use generics it will fail as the key is String  . I just wanted to know I mean why this limitation for values in map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `TreeMap` always sorts on keys.

As to why it's not "supported by default" -- it's because there doesn't exist a data structure in general that supports it efficiently.  It's not supported efficiently in *any* programming language, because the point of a `Map` is to be able to look things up by their key, and sorting by values means you *can't* organize the data in a way that makes it efficient to look things up by keys.

If you must sort a `Map`'s entries by value, you can use something like this:

```
List<Map.Entry<Foo, Bar>> entryList = 
  new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Foo, Bar>>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(entryList, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Foo, Bar>>() {
  public int compare(Map.Entry<Foo, Bar> entry1, Map.Entry<Foo, Bar> entry2) {
    return entry1.getValue().compareTo(entry2.getValue());
  }
});
```

Alternately, if you like, you can use an alternate comparator to compare the values if you don't control the implementation of the value type.

Comment: Ya , I agree but there might be many scenarios where in the value will be an object and we want to sort over that . I think I can implement comparable for the object and sort it . But what If I don have the access to that object :( .

Comment: I've added some explanation as to how to order the entries of a `Map` by values, but the point remains -- it's simply not possible to write an efficient `Map` implementation that sorts entries by value, so you have to do it some other way than using a `Map`.

Comment: Ya correct , I know that workaround for sorting it based on values by using collections utility sort method. But I was curious why there was not comparator on values for Map or why is it restricted only for keys

Comment: As I've said several times above, it's impossible or extremely awkward to provide an efficient `Map` implementation that sorts based on the values.

Comment: Ya this makes sense  " Map is to be able to look things up by their key, and sorting by values means you can't organize the data in a way that makes it efficient to look things up by keys " . Hmmm okay I will go by that.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation for TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29) you'll see it says:

> Constructs a new, empty tree map, ordered according to the given comparator. All keys inserted into the map must be mutually comparable by the given comparator: comparator.compare(k1, k2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any keys k1 and k2 in the map. If the user attempts to put a key into the map that violates this constraint, the put(Object key, Object value) call will throw a ClassCastException.

The main point here is that it's comparing **keys**, but you're casting the key (ie: a `String`) into a `Person`.

Comment: Ya I could get that . But why is that allowed only for keys. Is there any specific reason why its not allowed for values . I mean I can use a List for values and Sort it but . Why this limitation for Map values.

Comment: You should check out @LouisWasserman's answer for a reason for that.  I'd just be repeating what he says.  But, something you might be able to do (really depends on the domain of the problem) is to put that String **in** the Person object and then use a List and sort it by a `Comparator` that looks inside the Person object for that field.  Alternatively, you could create a temp class that has a `name` and a `person` field and then sort a `List` of those.

Comment: Ya I know thw workaround for sorting it based on Values . But I mean Ya I know that workaround . But am still not satisfied as to why is it limited only to keys .      Also there might be many scenarios where in the value will be an object and we want to sort over that . I think I can implement comparable for the object and sort it . But what If I don have the access to that object :(